# DynamoDB networking error when deploying to production

Tags: amazon-web-services, networking, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-iam

I've been trying to successfully setup my DynamoDB in AWS and have had some difficulty. I have no issue at all when using DynamoDB Local - only when trying to run in production (DynamoDB).

I'm using Vogels for DynamoDB with my Node.js application. Now receving a networking error.

> { [NetworkingError: connect ECONNREFUSED 52.94.24.26:8000]
>     message: 'connect ECONNREFUSED 52.94.24.26:8000',
>     code: 'NetworkingError',
>     errno: 'ECONNREFUSED',
>     syscall: 'connect',
>     address: '52.94.24.26',
>     port: 8000,
>     region: 'eu-west-1',
>     hostname: 'dynamodb.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com',
>     retryable: true,
>     time: Sun Dec 25 2016 09:29:37 GMT+0000 (UTC) }

I've checked the IAM user and verified the permissions are set to **AmazonDynamoDBFullAccess - AWS Managed policy**

What else am I missing here?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The server your code is running on doesn't have a network connection to the AWS API. Please provide more information about the server and network.

Comment: @MarkB - thanks you were right. the script was running from the jenkins machine which didn't have access. once i moved it over to the instance (where app runs) it was able to connect properly :)